# How to use joinFieldNamesSubset from QgsVectorJoinInfo class

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, attribute-joins

I have written a small python plugin to refresh a join on a point layer in QGIS.

```
point_layer=None
for lyr1 in QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers().values():
  if lyr1.name() == "point_layer":
    point_layer = lyr1

text_table=None
for lyr2 in QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers().values():
if lyr2.name() == "text_table":
  text_table = lyr2

POINT_ID='ID'
TEXT_ID='ID'
joinObject = QgsVectorJoinInfo()
joinObject.joinLayerId = text_table.id()
QgsVectorLayer.removeJoin(point_layer, text_table.id())
joinObject.joinFieldName = TEXT_ID
joinObject.targetFieldName = POINT_ID
joinObject.memoryCache = True
point_layer.addJoin(joinObject)
```

I tried to get a subset of fields to be used from joined layer text_layer.

```
joinObject.joinFieldNamesSubset = 'TYPE'
```

There is no error, but it joins all the fields, not only the field 'TYPE' (attribute of layer text_layer).

How can I set the attributes I want to join? And where do I have to call `joinFieldNamesSubset`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the following line instead:

```
joinObject.setJoinFieldNamesSubset(['TYPE'])
```

---

And as it is a list, you can specify which fields you only want to have joined:

```
joinObject.setJoinFieldNamesSubset(['Field_1', 'Field_2', 'Field_3'])
```

Comment: Note: values of field subsets have to be in order with the attributes of the joined layer. Otherwise fields and values doesn't match (e.g. `joinObject.setJoinFieldNamesSubset(['Field_3', 'Field_2', 'Field_1'])` doesn't work for me).

Comment: @Stefan - That's a good point, thanks for mentioning that =)